# I've made a business page for my father and I and I want him to get the notifications

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I thought I was being nice by creating a business page for my fathers fishing guide service (and that has really worked nicely) but now that I am rarely a part of his business due to distance, everyone who comments on the facebook thinking I'm my father.. He doesn't get notifications when someone comments on a picture or sends HIM a message. I feel aweful about it because it's part of my page.. Is there some way I can link him to the business page so he too can get notifications??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code, as well as what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you go to your page and click "Edit Page" ->"Admin Roles" you should be able to type in his email or username and add him as an admin to the page. Then he should receive notifications as well